# Setting PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS to True is not re-raising exception in Flask production mode

Tags: python, flask

I know that debug mode sets PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS to True. And production mode sets PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS to False.

I also know that in production mode PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS value can be set to True (`app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True`).

[This article](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/?highlight=propagate#PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS) read that - if the PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS is True, then,

> Exceptions are re-raised rather than being handled by the app’s error
>   handlers. If not set, this is implicitly true if TESTING or DEBUG is
>   enabled.

In production mode when I register an error handler as follows: `@app.errorhandler(500)`. By default, `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` is False, and raising an AttributeError (`raise AttributeError`) from an endpoint hits the `@app.errorhandler(500)`. I understand this is because as shown in this [code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2ab91446f608755affba035650c1dd74b825a018/flask/app.py#L1446-L1450) the handler for 500 gets invoked with error as an argument to it. Had there been an AttributeHandler then it would have been invoked rathet than the 500. Now, if I change `app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True` and re-deploy the app, then for the same endpoint, flask shows a generic 500 Internal Server Error. I was expecting that the AttributeError exception will be re-raised. Why is this happening? Is it because it does get reraised but since there is no handler for the AttributeError so Flask gives a 500 error message as it is supposed to do that in production mode. Which code is responsible for this behaviour?

If the app is in debug mode, then by default unhandled errors are re-raised. However, if `app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = False`, then the 500 error handler handled the error. So PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS= False works well in debug mode. But PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS=True does not behave as expected in production mode. That is - it does not re-raise the error.

Comment: Are you using extensions such as Flask-RESTPlus? some of them wrap the original error handler and changes the error propagation.